# VueJs 2: map selected child checkboxes with the parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox, vuejs2

I have multiple roles and their permissions (checkboxes). So now when I select some permissions from role I need to map these permissions to be associated with the their role.

Result:
Here I'm getting selected checkboxes but also I need to map the role as a key

```
[ { "perm_id": 2, "perm_name": "Update" }, { "perm_id": 1, "perm_name": "Create" } ]
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checked_roles: [],
    roles: [
      {
       "role_id" : 1,
        "role_name" : 'Administrator',
        "perms" : [
         {
           "perm_id" : 1,
            "perm_name" : 'Create'
          },
          {
           "perm_id" : 2,
            'perm_name' : 'Update'
          },
          {
           "perm_id" : 3,
            'perm_name' : 'Delete'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
       "role_id" : 2,
        "role_name" : 'Moderator',
        "perms" : [
         {
           "perm_id" : 1,
            "perm_name" : 'Create'
          },
          {
           "perm_id" : 2,
            'perm_name' : 'Update'
          },
          {
           "perm_id" : 3,
            'perm_name' : 'Delete'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.role-row {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="role in roles" class="role-row">
    <label>{{role.role_name}}</label>
    <hr>
    <div v-for="perm in role.perms">
      <input type="checkbox" :value="perm" v-model="checked_roles"> {{ perm.perm_name }}
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <p>Selected roles and perms</p>
  {{checked_roles}}
</div>
```

Probably, I have to use computed property or watch method, but I'm new in the VueJs and I tried multiple times to resolve this, but without result.

The roles[] object should be returned but only with checked checkboxes. That's it.

```
// checked for example:
[
    {"role_id" : 1,"role_name" : 'Administrator',"perms" : [{"perm_id" : 1,"perm_name" : 'Create'}, {"perm_id" : 2,'perm_name' : 'Update'}]},
    {"role_id" : 2,"role_name" : 'Moderator',"perms" : [{"perm_id" : 1,"perm_name" : 'Create'}]}
]
```

Comment: Please don't use external code sites. Instead use a regular Stack snippet right in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<template>
<div>
    <div id="app">
        <div v-for="role in roles" class="role-row">
            <label>{{role.role_name}}</label>
            <hr>
            <div v-for="(perm,index) in role.perms">
                <input type="checkbox" @change="getRole(role,index)" :value="perm"  v-model="checked_roles"> {{ perm.perm_name }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <p>Selected roles and perms</p>
        {{checked_roles}}
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 data: {
        checked_roles: [],
        checked_roles_with_role_name: [],
        roles: [
            {
                "role_id" : 1,
                "role_name" : 'Administrator',
                "perms" : [
                    {
                        "perm_id" : 1,
                        "perm_name" : 'Create'
                    },
                    {
                        "perm_id" : 2,
                        'perm_name' : 'Update'
                    },
                    {
                        "perm_id" : 3,
                        'perm_name' : 'Delete'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "role_id" : 2,
                "role_name" : 'Moderator',
                "perms" : [
                    {
                        "perm_id" : 1,
                        "perm_name" : 'Create'
                    },
                    {
                        "perm_id" : 2,
                        'perm_name' : 'Update'
                    },
                    {
                        "perm_id" : 3,
                        'perm_name' : 'Delete'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    methods:{
        getRole(role,index){
            this.checked_roles_with_role_name={checked_roles:this.checked_roles,role_name:role.role_name}
        }
    }
```

SO "checked_roles_with_role_name" data property should hold selected role and their role names

Comment: I don't need only the name of the role. I need to be binded as an object. Because in future I can pass more information in the role which I'm using it to display in the front-end

Comment: Ok I understand , just give me a moment let me  see if i can fix it.

Comment: Okay :)

The roles[] object should be returned but only with checked permissions, that's it... :)

Comment: I dont get what you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Best technique for syncing object from child to direct parent is to use .sync modifier. More info [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier).